# Smart Capture form to show choices from a DE?

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm wondering if someone can possibly shed some light here, I have a smart capture form I'm building that has an add/update feature because of the primary key of "emailaddress"

I am pulling in the email address into a query string, which works great... the only thing though, is that I would like it to show a user's choice if they have already put in values into the DE previously.

For example here is the front end of the form, I would like it to show the choices a recipient already has before loading the page - similar to how it's pulling in their subscriber record. Is that possible? This page was built all with smart capture / cloud pages and a little ampscript to pull in their email address.

https://mcz5-l55x3kttqydms2vxt--5zkq.pub.sfmc-content.com/mrg20v12z2n?qs=ab0a1daabd536d524f3fc9c9356ad12470df153ed5fa9d014d7e7139de6192b957461dba656d17367648849aeb16d4db

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a preference center. You can look up values in the DE based on the email address you already have using the `Lookup` function. This assumes the email address variable is `EmailAddress`.

```
%%[
VAR @EventBooleanNullable2Value  
SET @EventBooleanNullable2Value = 
Lookup("[DE-NAME]","EventBoolean2Nullable","emailaddress", @EmailAddress)    
]%%
```

And then in your HTML for the form you set the value of the `input` element like this below, assuming the values for the "EventBooleanNullable2" in the DE are `true` or `false`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="EventBooleanNullable2" data-field-type="Boolean" 
%%[IF @EventBooleanNullable2Value == "true" THEN]%%checked%%[ENDIF]%%>
```

https://ampscript.guide/lookup/

Comment: ah very cool - thank you!  yes this is exactly the kind of thing I was trying to do, essentially I just want to emulate a preference center so that the client can go in and update it themselves without a ton of coding expertise.